# Brake pedal going to the floor

Tags: brakes

I tried to change my front brake pads, I've done it before and it's not a difficult task, but I couldnt get the pads out and as the sun was going down I compressed the calliper (with the brake reservoir cap off, reassembled the brake and put the wheel back on etc. Now my pedal is sinking to the floor. It's an 09 fiesta style if It helps. Any suggestions?

Comment: It may go to the floor several times since you collapsed the caliper pistons, stroke the brake pedal 10 times.

Comment: Be careful using the full travel of the pedal - the seals in the master cylinder can get damaged due to the worn part of the bore... I changed my pads the other day and just pumped the pedal using only 2 inches of movement - worked fine and brakes great...

Comment: Yeah I tried that and it's still sinking to the floor

Comment: Do you think I might have somehow got air in the system?

Comment: Any sign of leaking under the car or hood?

Comment: Nah nothing at all.

Comment: ten may not be enough.  does it sound like it's doing something?  You know, the whooshing sound?

Comment: The whooshing sound?